# I uitableview the (cell = nil) always not call?

Tags: ios, uitableview

in the ui tableview cell,
the statement if (cell == nil)  is not called.

Because when i initialize the cell outside the if statement, the talbe will have some wrong label in wrong row.

how can I initialize my cell?

The @"tttestttt" NS LOG is not all the time when the table is created.

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

```
static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"GroupsCell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    NSLog(@"tttesttttt");
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault  reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` always return a cell if you're using Storyboard.

Answer (score 1):

Use the more convenient method `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:` which returns always a valid cell.

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {    
    static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"GroupsCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier 
                                                        forIndexPath:indexPath];

    ...

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

make Identifier not a fixed value

make it as index.row (convert  to string  as identity)

your wrong may be crate by cell refuse